# Editing json file in line with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file like this:

```json
{
"arrays": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "properties": [
        {
          "type": "app",
          "url": "https://example.com",
          "checksum": "d6fd580fe890b826250aa5d5a88bcdb28839cff4d447ba51536cda4ceae89c4e"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to change the type to something else, delete the url and checksum key and add a file key in their place with a value.

The final thing should be:

```json
{
"arrays": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "properties": [
        {
          "type": "Bar",
          "file": "filename"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I do this inline with `jq`

I got upto modifying the type value:

```bash
jq '(.arrays[]| select(.name == "foo").properties[]).type |= "Bar"' test.json
```

Comment: Do you want this to affect all items in `.arrays` or just those that match `.name == "foo"`? Do you want to change all items of the `.properties` array, or just those that match `.type == "app"`? Are there other fields in those items that you want to keep, so `.url` and `.checksum` have to be explicitly deleted, or could you build a new object just containing the altered `.type` and the added `.file` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace the whole properties field :

```
jq '(.arrays[]| select(.name == "foo")).properties |= [{
    "type" : "bar",
    "file" : "filename"
}]' test.json
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/xupiiF5mz_a).

Comment: Thanks I used this except it's missing a `[ ]` in properties. should be `properties |= [{"type" : "bar", "file" : "filename"}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
.arrays[].properties |= map({ type: "FOOBAR", file: "someFile" })
```

Will result in:

```json
{
  "arrays": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "properties": [
        {
          "type": "FOOBAR",
          "file": "someFile"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

###### [Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/CF5ZR9G3dEh)